# Make Update to a live iPhone app

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, sdk, app-store

I have an iPhone app which is aleready live on the app store...Now I want to make small updates to the app (fixes and adding iAd)

How do I submit the new updated app..Will that create a new version OR is that not required?

Also in iTunes Connect, I do not see any link which says Submit update or new version..

Do I first have to upload via Loader ...Please guide me. Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should update the "version" field in your .plist, then submit a new binary.

In the application page, there is a "Add Version" button in the lower right corner, as follows:
[image: Example Application Page]

Click "Add Version", clarify what is being updated/fixed/upgraded in the new version, make sure that all the other fields are correct, and then submit.

After that, you will have to use the Application Loader (Mac App) to upload your binary.

No matter how small or insignificant the updates are, you *have* to add a new version. Note that the *current* version will not be removed from the store, so you will not lose sales (or downloads).

Also, note that while there *are* technical ways to slightly circumvent this (e.g., by downloading dynamic code from the internet), such practices are strictly forbidden and will cause your app to be rejected.

Comment: Yes it is - unless you only need to alter the app description (or snapshot images), which can be done without uploading a new binary.

Comment: Ok..So to update the version number, I only need to update it in the .plist file say from 1.0 now to 1.1 ...Is there similar entry required on the iTunes connect page..

Comment: @hmthr no, because the new version number will be read from your bundle directly.

Comment: Thx a lot...Just one last question..Actually I am using XCode 4 now (and seems a bit new)..I plan to upload the updated app now...But not sure how do I do that..Should I just do Build and then "Reveal in Finder" and then upload the compressed file..

Comment: You might do that, or you might Build-Archive, then Share the resulting archive as an .ipa file and upload that. It is easier.

Comment: Really sorry..But do you have any reference for the same (Build-Archive, then Share the resulting archive as an .ipa file)..like the steps..

Comment: Yes: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/DistApps/DistApps.html