# Launch Add-on for iphone app

Tags: ios, iphone, add-on

I am currently developing an iphone application that will be sold for a fixed amount (say $X). As part of the future plan for the application, i would like to launch an Add-on for the application ( say $Y). What i want is that users who have already paid $X should be only charged $Y when they purchase the Add-on and new users purchase it for $(X+Y). Is it possible to launch paid Add-ons for the application independently. Any other ideas how to go about this process?

Comment: Did you considered In-App purchases?

Comment: Basically, the content inside the app is not paid. I thought the In-App purchase is for the content inside the App. Sorry, i am a newbie with ios thing.

Comment: There is no such thing as "add-ons" in iOS. Using In-App purchase, you can enable additional functionality within the app.

Comment: But that functionality will not be there in the first version. After launching the first version, we will develop second part (Add-on etc) and then release it. Is selling the entire app again the only possibility?

Comment: When you develop the 2nd part, you submit an update to the original app with the new functionality as IAP.

Comment: @maddy. Thanks for valuable suggestions. I am starting to see the big picture now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been mentioned, there is no such thing as an 'add-on'.

What you would have to do is implement in-app purchasing in the second version of your app. Once the user updated their app to the new version they would then have the facility to buy this new functionality from within the app. When people buy something through the in-app purchase, you can either download the new content from a server or you can use conditional statements to enable this content.

Comment: Hi.I got your point.One question- will people who have paid for the first version be charged again for downloading the second version.Is there a way to find/configure if a user buying the second version is updating the first version or a new first time user. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: No. Once a user has purchased an app they are entitled to any future update for free. For further clarification on how you could provide updates you could have a look at this Stack Overflow: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034555/make-update-to-a-live-iphone-app)

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. There is no way to determine what price a user purchased an iPhone application at -- all buyers are treated equally.